# Check for duplicate primary key before inserting to Z table

Tags: abap

I have a Ztable which has 14 fields out of which the first 5 are key fields.

I also have a z program which displays a alv Grid. We can add entries to the table via this Z program by pressing the (+) button via the tool bar.

So when i enter a bunch of value via the grid ( copy paste) i get all the values through internal table. I do like this as of now,
Key 1 ,2 and 3 are company code , sales org and another value through selection screen. I dont think my below code is very efficient, pls suggest to improve this.

```
  loop at datatab_y.
IF datatab_y-key3 IS NOT INITIAL.
  SORT datatab_y by key3.
  at new key3.
    new_row = sy-tabix.
  endat.
  at end of key3.
    check sy-tabix > new_row.
    lv_dupflg = datatab_y-key3.
    perform send_dupkey_msg USING lv_dupflg.
  endat.
ELSEIF datatab_y-key4 IS NOT INITIAL.
   SORT datatab_y by key4.
  at new key4.
    new_row = sy-tabix.
  endat.
  at end of key4.
    check sy-tabix > new_row.
    lv_dupflg = datatab_y-key4.
    perform send_dupkey_msg USING lv_dupflg.
  endat.
ENDIF.
```

Comment: Why do you think it's not efficient?

Comment: i am sorting the internal table for every iteration. This itab is expected to have 10 k lines of data already plus the one we are adding via the alv grid. I thought i can get a different way to check for duplicates before appending. In my recent code i am sorting by key and erdat too.

Comment: Looping at an internal table and sorting this internal table inside the loop will lead to the runtime error TABLE_FREE_IN_LOOP, so it's more than not efficient, it doesn't work at all. So, first try a few things until it executes.

Comment: Thanks , i moved the sort before loop like this.
    `SORT datatab_y by erdat DESCENDING.`
This  should help i believe .

Comment: Okay i am writing my question/requirement in a different way. I have itab X which has 1000 lines and through ALV GRID i am inserting 20 lines. So not itab y has 1020 lines. Before committing i.e inserting to ztable i should check for duplicates.

The z table has first 6 fields as primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to keep the code short, based on the `COLLECT` statement.

This way, you store the values of each key field in a dedicated "implicit hash table" (effect of COLLECT on a standard table), and if the value already exists in the table, COLLECT does not add a new line.

```
DATA: saved_number_of_lines TYPE i,
      key3s LIKE STANDARD TABLE OF datatab_y-key3 WITH KEY table_line,
      key4s LIKE STANDARD TABLE OF datatab_y-key4 WITH KEY table_line.

CLEAR: key3s, key4s.

LOOP AT datatab_y.

  saved_number_of_lines = lines( key3s ).
  COLLECT datatab_y-key3 INTO key3s.
  IF lines( key3s ) = saved_number_of_lines.
    " it means that COLLECT has not added a new line, i.e. the value already exists
    PERFORM send_dupkey_msg USING datatab_y-key3.
  ENDIF.

  saved_number_of_lines = lines( key4s ).
  COLLECT datatab_y-key4 INTO key4s.
  IF lines( key4s ) = saved_number_of_lines.
    PERFORM send_dupkey_msg USING datatab_y-key4.
  ENDIF.

ENDLOOP.

FREE: key3s, key4s. " free memory if needed
```

PS: here, I use your style of coding, although it would be nice to not using "header lines".

EDIT: my bad, syntax error because of `lines( datatab_y-key3 )` and `lines( datatab_y-key4 )`, replaced with `lines( key3s )` and `lines( key4s )`

Comment: Thanks @SandraRossi, I get it (almost).  datatab_y internal table has all values (existing and newly added), however datatab_y-key3 and datatab_y-key4  where do i source these from? . My key 3 and key 4 are prdha and matnr respectively.

Comment: Also 
    `saved_number_of_lines = lines( datatab_y-key3 ).`  datatab_y-key3 should be itab right , not work area.

Comment: @Winona sorry my bad. You're right, I have corrected as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to declare your internal table already **SORTED** with a **UNIQUE KEY**.
That way, your table will always be sorted and have no duplicates.

For example :

```
DATA : itab TYPE SORTED TABLE OF mara WITH UNIQUE KEY matnr.
```

If you do so, you will have to change your append with **INSERT ... INTO ...** .

Comment: thanks, however i cannot change the itab type, this itab is being used at many places in the program and it has 5 primary keys and i have to compare mainly two keys. one is prdha and one is matnr.